# Talkative/Outspoken/Bounty badges' purpose on MSO

Tags: discussion, badges

In the Meta StackOverflow badges list, we can find these two:

- <kbd>Talkative</kbd>: Posted 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in chat
- <kbd>Outspoken</kbd>: Posted 10 messages in chat that were starred by 10 different users

But (tell me if I'm wrong) there's no chat dedicated to MSO.
Can these badge be earned? If no, what's their purpose?

There's the same problem with the <kbd>Area 51</kbd> badge, but this was precisely left to let people discovering the Area 51.

Do we really need these two badges on MSO? People using MSO probably already know the chat, and this chat is not even usable **for** MSO, all "credits" goes for SO badge.

***EDIT: same problem for all bounty-related badges***

Comment: a solution would be to make [Lounge C++](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) into chat dedicated to MSO (and to Area 51 for that matter)

Comment: This is the same as some badges on SO not being possible.

Comment: @Joe The only one badge which cannot be earned on SO is `Area 51`. On MSO, we've got several badges merged from SO, but without any purpose.

Comment: Are you missing the beta badge, and the pro-tem moderator badge? Not to mention the one that is already retired.

Comment: The Beta badge has been earned by 2.5k users, it seems legit to keep it, to encourage people to be active in future beta StackExchange sites.

Comment: *All* badges are visible on *all* sites. Why should MSO be any different?

Comment: I though badges were chosen per site.